# Windows 8 continually goes to sleep and I must enter a password, regardless of settings

Tags: windows-8

I have a new computer with Windows 8.  I have all of the settings set that the computer won't enter sleep mode or go to screen lock.  I also have it set that local administrators or users won't need to enter a password, but my screen continually goes to sleep and I have to enter a password.  This happens when I am a local administrator or if I am entered as a microsoft account administrator.

Please help.

Comment: When you say you have set *all of the settings* regarding this matter, exactly which settings are you talking about? With just this information, it's hard to tell what's wrong.

Comment: What about screen saver settings ? Is `On resume display logon screen` disabled ?

Answer (score 1):

Open Control Panel and go to Hardware and Sound -> Power Options.  Click on the "Change Plan Settings" link next to your currently selected power plan.  Under both On Battery and Plugged In, change "Turn the display off" and "Put the display to sleep" to "never."  As for your password issue, click "Change advanced power settings" and set both values under "Require a password on wakeup to "never."  Click "Apply" then "Save Changes."